# Apache basic auth and flask token auth together

Tags: python, angularjs, apache, authentication

I have API written in flask and I use JWT token for authorization. I would like to protect my staging environment from unautorized access, so I added apache basic authentication, but it uses same "Authorization" header, and angular replaces my basic auth header with JWT header.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Maybe can I change Apache Authorization header to different key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doubtful that you would be able to change the authorization header on apache (I imagine that it is hard coded to that, as web browsers wouldn't know to send the actual request in a different header). This is just my intuition though, and might very well be wrong.

If you used flask-jwt-extended instead of flask-jwt, you could change the header which contains the JWT using the JWT_HEADER_NAME option (http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html). Full disclosure, I'm the author of this extension.

If you want to continue to use flask-jwt, you can probably do this by utilizing one of the jwt_*_callback decorators, or by sub-classing flask-jwt and overwriting the method that checks for the JWT in the authorization header.